# How to get a logged in user account data including memberID so user can edit or delete their account?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a member page that lands after user signs in. From there I need to populate that page with all their data in a form format (same as the one they filled out initially) so they can edit and update/save.

```
<form>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit My Account        
        </legend>

        <div>
            <label class="label" for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="user" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="2" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="email" type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" tabindex="3" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="label" for="password">Password</label>
            <input class="password" type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="4" required />
        </div> 
        <div>
            <label class="label" for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
            <input class="password" type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" tabindex="5" required />
        </div> 
        <div>
            <input class="showbox" type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" tabindex="6" onFocus="this.tabIndex=1;"onBlur="this.tabIndex=6;"required />
            <label for="terms">I agree to the <a href="/terms.php">Terms</a></label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <div>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" />
        </div> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Secondly I want them to be able to delete their entire account with a "Delete My Account" button via a input type 'submit' that would appear on same member page.

```
<fieldset>
<form action="delete.php?" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $members['memberID']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete My Account">
</form>
</filedset>
```

I've been searching for days now... mostly this platform and have not found any sound solution(s).

I'm using MySQL db using PDO $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO... to create insert for new users and that all works fine.

I include a separate connection config file for db connection as well.

I created a delete.php file for the statement.

```
<?php require('config.php');

$id=$_SESSION['memberID'];

$stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM members where memberID = $id');

?>
```

I'm not able to find a solution to populate the member page with logged in user data then edit and update it and/or capture the users logged in memberID to submit the delete account request using that memberID.

Some guidance would be appreciated, Thanks!

Here is my login.php code

```
<?php
//include config
require_once('config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: memberpage.php'); } 

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header('Location: memberpage.php');
exit;

} else {
$error[] = '<h2 class="red ctr thanks">Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.</h2>';
}

}//end if submit

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: Please attach PHP login code so we can help you in better way

Comment: remove memebID from "form" tag as you are already added in hidden field inside form.  <form action='delete.php' method="post">

Comment: once user logged in store user id into the session variable. use that session value on your landing page. use select query to fetch information from database of that user and display at there.

Comment: Thanks to you all as I have hopefully followed each of your suggestions via an edit to the initial post to each of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

At first you must set id user.after login user in admin page 
and next you can use of that

```
    <?php 
  $userId= $_GET['id'];//get user id you can use session also
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $email    = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      $passwordConfirm = $_POST['passwordConfirm'];
      $terms = $_POST['terms'];
      if (($password===$passwordConfirm) and ($terms===1)){
               $query = "UPDATE members SET username  = :username  ,email = :email,"
                    ."password = :password WHERE id = :id";
             $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
             $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->bindParam(':id',$userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      }
      }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE id = `$userId`"; //Get user info
    $sth  = $db->prepare($query);
    $sth ->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result) {
        // output data of each row
     foreach($result as $row){
         $username =   $row['username'];
         $email    =  $row['email'];
         $password = $row['password'];

      }

  }
?>

<form  method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS); ?>">

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit My Account        
        </legend>

        <div>
            <label class="label" for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="user" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>" tabindex="2" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="email" type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo  $email?>" tabindex="3" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="label" for="password">Password</label>
            <input class="password" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>" id="password" tabindex="4" required />
        </div> 
        <div>
            <label class="label" for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
            <input class="password" type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" tabindex="5" required />
        </div> 
        <div>
            <input class="showbox" type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" tabindex="6" onFocus="this.tabIndex=1;"onBlur="this.tabIndex=6;"required />
            <label for="terms">I agree to the <a href="/terms.php">Terms</a></label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <div>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" />
        </div> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Pedram Shabani for your reply. I made your recommended changes and changed GET to SESSION in your second line. I am however getting an error from the PHP code from "unexpected "}" in lines 17 and 18. I moved those closing brackets to the bottom of the PHP code but then got another error. Could you please check your code to see what the issue is? Thanks :)

Comment: your welcome .i edited again.you can say me about your error??

Comment: Thank you for update. I'm still having an issue. I had originally used "memberID" as column name in memebrs table but I have now changed it to "id" and revised all related files too. Seems lines 2 and 21 are causing issue. "Notice: Undefined index: id in /memberpage.php on line 2 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause'' /memberpage.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /memberpage.php(21): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM `...') #1 {main} thrown in /memberpage.php on line 21". I changed userId to id and sth to stmt.

Comment: do you  have id column??plz be careful mysql and php  is sensitive to small and large letters.for example if you define ID column then you can not write id or iD  in your query.

Comment: Yes I have a column named "id" it is lower case "id" Just to be less confusing I have refined the form to just 'username' and 'email'. I already have functionality to reset password from login page. Currently I'm not getting any errors but the table is not updating for example if I just change username from form. Please see above edited code that I refined from yours to fit my new example. Thanks.